# How to use ISODate to query in Rust / Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I have a problem with date in Rust and Mongodb.
I use the mongodb Rust driver and aggregation [close resembles this tutorial.](https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/rust-quickstart-aggregation/). My problem is when I try to use query with ISODate, such as `"tomatoes.lastUpdated": {"$gte": date}` to query every entry that has its `lastUpdated` value newer than `date`.

The code below throws `error[E0277]: the trait bound "Bson: From<mongodb::bson::DateTime>" is not satisfied`

```
use mongodb::bson::doc;
use mongodb::bson::DateTime;
use chrono::prelude::*;
use chrono::{Utc};

let date = DateTime(Utc::now()); // I use mongodb::bson::DateTime
let pipeline = vec![
   doc! {
      "$match": {
         "tomatoes.lastUpdated": {"$gte": date} // what the type for date variable here should be ?
         //^the trait `From<mongodb::bson::DateTime>` is not implemented for `Bson`
      }
   },

   // sort by year, ascending:
   doc! {"$sort": { "year": 1}},
];
```

Cargo.toml:

```
serde = "1.0.124"
serde_json = "1.0.64"
mongodb = "2.0.0-alpha.1"
```

Thank you in advance .

Comment: where does `doc` macro come from I guess you don't use the same version of bson than mongo 2.0

Comment: have you try to use chrono type directly ?

Comment: this chrono ? https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.parse_from_str

Comment: what is `Utc` ? use the type returned directly by `Utc::now()` don't warp it in this warper

Comment: OK. this works now. I use `Utc::now()` and change the date type into `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>`. Turns out I don't need `bson::DateTime`

Comment: But there's a weird thing with mongodb / Rust. If I want to store a DateTime into database with Serde (Serialize), I had to use  `mongodb::bson::DateTime`, but if I use it for query, the original `chrono::DateTime` is enough

Comment: mongodb is not very well coded in my opinion, but I can't say it's doesn't work and it's not "that" bad but yeah... if you search you can find sometime me being not very happy on some thread concerning mongodb design choice rust or just mongo itself. ;) for example no unsigned type, the spec required ordered json... (but mongodb is still WAY better than ELK so....)

Answer (score 1):

The `From<bson::DateTime>` implementation for `Bson` was accidentally omitted in that release of the `bson` crate, but it has since been introduced. If you update your dependency on `mongodb` or `bson` to the latest beta (2.0.0-beta.3), `bson::DateTime` can be used for both the query and with serde, so your original example should work with the modification of `DateTime(Utc::now())` to `DateTime::now()`.

Note that in the more recent versions, the `chrono` interop is gated behind the `chrono-0_4` feature flag in `bson` or the `bson-chrono-0_4` feature flag in `mongodb`. This includes the `From<chrono::DateTime>` implementation for `Bson` and the `chrono` releated [serde helpers](https://docs.rs/bson/2.0.0-beta.3/bson/serde_helpers/index.html). This isn't currently documented very well, but we plan to fix that before the 2.0.0 stable release. As mentioned above, the `chrono` feature flag isn't actually required for this example though, since `bson::DateTime` contains all the necessary functionality on its own.